# Carry Original File Name to FTP endpoint

Tags: mule

Using Mule Studio

Version: 3.5.0
Build Id: 201402101410

I have a very simple flow. I need to pick up a file from one ftp server and transfer it to another ftp server. When the file is written to the target, the filename looks like some kind of UUId rather than the original file name. How do I get the file name to carry through? I have tried #[header:originalFilename] but that throws an error so I assume that maybe it is only for file connectors. Here is my flow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" version="CE-3.4.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
<context:property-placeholder location="environment.properties"/>
    <flow name="sli-ftpFlow1" doc:name="sli-ftpFlow1">
        <ftp:inbound-endpoint host="${local.ftp.host}" port="${local.ftp.port}" path="${local.ftp.path}" user="${local.ftp.user}" password="${local.ftp.pass}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" pollingFrequency="${local.ftp.pollingFreq}" binary="true" passive="false"/>
        <logger message="Transferring file:" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="${sli.ftp.host}" port="${sli.ftp.port}" path="${sli.ftp.path}" user="${sli.ftp.user}" password="${sli.ftp.pass}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Stack Trace:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'sli-ftp'                                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2014-03-19 22:10:38,058 [[sli-ftp].sli-ftpFlow1.stage1.02] INFO  org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor - Transferring file:
2014-03-19 22:10:38,071 [[sli-ftp].connector.ftp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager - Initialising: 'connector.ftp.mule.default.dispatcher.1035665885'. Object is: FtpMessageDispatcher
2014-03-19 22:10:38,071 [[sli-ftp].connector.ftp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] INFO  org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager - Starting: 'connector.ftp.mule.default.dispatcher.1035665885'. Object is: FtpMessageDispatcher
2014-03-19 22:10:38,078 [[sli-ftp].connector.ftp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Streaming failed. Could not get output stream. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=ftp://esbuser%40newpig.com:<password>@webuatint/SLI-Mock, connector=FtpConnector
{
  name=connector.ftp.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=a40c648
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[ftp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.ftp.webuatint.21.SLI.Mock', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[header:originalFilename]}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: byte[]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:originalFilename" returned null but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException)
  org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils:239 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/RequiredValueException.html)
2. Streaming failed. Could not get output stream. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=ftp://esbuser%40newpig.com:<password>@webuatint/SLI-Mock, connector=FtpConnector
{
  name=connector.ftp.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=a40c648
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[ftp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.ftp.webuatint.21.SLI.Mock', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[header:originalFilename]}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.ftp.FtpConnector:602 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException: Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:originalFilename" returned null but a value was required.
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyInternal(ExpressionUtils.java:239)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyWithScope(ExpressionUtils.java:67)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyWithScope(ExpressionUtils.java:50)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Stack Trace with #[header:originalFilename] in Logger:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'sli-ftp'                                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2014-03-20 08:15:35,918 [[sli-ftp].sli-ftpFlow1.stage1.02] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:originalFilename" returned null but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException). Message payload is of type: byte[]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:originalFilename" returned null but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException)
  org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils:239 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/RequiredValueException.html)
2. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:originalFilename" returned null but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException). Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:35 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException: Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "outbound:originalFilename" returned null but a value was required.
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyInternal(ExpressionUtils.java:239)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyWithScope(ExpressionUtils.java:67)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyWithScope(ExpressionUtils.java:50)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: #[header:originalFilename] should work ok. What is the error?

Comment: How many time have I read (or said) "include a stack trace". Sorry about that. I edited the question to include the stack trace. I also updated the flow to include the #[header:originalFilename] in the outbound connector. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't really explain anything... Try outputting #[message] in the logger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MEL: #[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename].

I think the scope is the issue.

This was changed in 3.4  -http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+ESB+3.4.0+Release+Notes

Mule 3.4+ originalFilename is in the inbound scope. So use: #[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]

Mule < 3.4 originalFilename is in the outbound scope. So use: #[message.outboundProperties.originalFilename]

Issue is documented here: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6743

Comment: Thanks! I just remembered to add the Mule Version but you were ahead of me.