# Is there a way to set filename on ftp connector on Mulesoft?

Tags: ftp, mulesoft

i'm trying using FTP Connector to copy file from local machine to FTP server.
It works well, and copy is ok, but on FTP server i'm able only to save dat file.
Is there a way to specify FileName?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Mule 4, you just use the [path attribute](https://docs.mulesoft.com/ftp-connector/1.5/ftp-write#embedded-dataweave-transformations) to specify the name:

```
<ftp:write config-ref="FTP_Config" doc:name="Write" path="demo.txt">
   ...
```

In Mule 3 there is an outputPattern attribute that is similar. For example [to carry the original file name from a previous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22531423/721855):

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="/some/directory" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]"/>
```